# Delete a certain object form an array in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to remove a particular chapter from a course from my MongoDB.
For example i want to remove "chapterid": 5 from "courseid" 1.
This is what i am trying right now:

```js
db.users.update({
            $and:
                [
                    {
                        "email": roshan_raj@gmail.com
                    },
                    {
                        "courses.courseid": 1
                    }
                ]
        },
            {
                $pull: {
                    "courses": {
                        "chapterid": 5
                    }
                }
            });
```

But this query is deleting both the object where there is a chapterid: 5

This is how my DB looks like.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e94393709d9194874cdb1d3"),
        "email" : "roshan_raj@gmail.com",
        "courses" : [
                {
                        "courseid" : "1",
                        "chapterid" : 5
                },
                {
                        "courseid" : "2",
                        "chapterid" : 5
                },
                {
                        "courseid" : "2",
                        "chapterid" : 6
                },
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: have you tried updatin the `"courses.courseid" : "1"` because in your collection they are being stored as string not a number

Comment: just fyi: you can also use: $and condition like this if you have nothing complex in your select query `db.users.update({
                        "email": "roshan_raj@gmail.com",
                        "courses.courseid": "1"
        },{
                $pull: {
                    "courses": {
                        "chapterid": 5
                    }
                }
            });`